# Failed to `bundle install` in CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circleci

I am getting errors while running `bundle install` in CircleCI.

**circle.yml**

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get clean; sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp; sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial; sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0; sudo apt-get install firefox; sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

  override:
    - bundle install:
        timeout: 180
```

**Error message:**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.8.0
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161127-19628-guj91w.rb extconf.rb
cd src/ && /usr/bin/qmake /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.8.0/src/webkit_server.pro -o Makefile.webkit_server
cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.8.0/src'
g++ -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -x c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server.gch/c++
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QtCore:108:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork/QtNetwork:3,
                 from stable.h:30:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentfilter.h: In function ‘QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineStarter<void> QtConcurrent::filterInternal(Sequence&, KeepFunctor, ReduceFunctor)’:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentfilter.h:108:47: warning: typedef ‘Iterator’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
     typedef typename Sequence::const_iterator Iterator;
                                               ^
g++ -c -include build/webkit_server -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -o build/BlockUrl.o BlockUrl.cpp
g++ -c -include build/webkit_server -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -o build/AllowUrl.o AllowUrl.cpp
g++ -c -include build/webkit_server -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -o build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp
g++ -c -include build/webkit_server -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -o build/FindModal.o FindModal.cpp
```

Please give me your advice!
Regards,

Anthony

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

then

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.8.0'
```

I hope this will work

Comment: which version of `ubuntu` you are using?

Comment: I use CircleCI, i am not sure which version, but when i run `sudo apt-get update;` i see log get data from `http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com`